# Reference to Semi-Statistical Optimal Control Theory

Tags: reference-request, oc.optimization-and-control, quantum-mechanics, statistical-physics

I don't know what to call what I want to do, so I'll explain and please refer me to texts and papers.

Given a standard control problem,
\begin{align}
\min_{u(t), W} &\int dt\ f(x(t), u(t); W) \\
\text{s.t.} &\ \dot{x} = g(x, u; W)
\end{align}
where $ W \in \mathbb{R}^N $ and are simple design parameters.

Certain problems make it extremely difficult to find numerical optima for $ W $ due to high amounts of non-linearity, so I was thinking of doing a sort of statistical approach from Statistical Mechanics/Feynman Path Integrals like,

The partition function might normally look like
\begin{align}
Z[x_f, x_i, T] = \int Dx\ D\lambda\ \exp\left\{\beta \int dt\ f(x(t), u(t); W) + \lambda (\dot{x} - g(x, u; W))\right\}
\end{align}
[See Klauder 2000](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0003297)

I was thinking of integrating over $ W $ as well such that in the limit that $ \beta \rightarrow +\infty $ the most optimal $ W $ dominate and so my probabilities will start to converge to my desired optima.

Can you please refer me to previous work on such a topic or with examples?